# Shadow Plugin Gradle: What does mergeServiceFiles() do?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

In my build.gradle file I need to add the line:

```
shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

Otherwise the jar does not run properly. I wonder what this line does exactly?
I use the Gradle plugin in Eclipse Luna. I create the jar on one Java project which depends on another one.

Answer (score 13):

`mergeServiceFiles` is declared exactly [here](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/tasks/ShadowJar.java#L131) and its implementation is as follows:

```
/**
 * Syntactic sugar for merging service files in JARs
 * @return
 */
public ShadowJar mergeServiceFiles() {
    try {
        transform(ServiceFileTransformer.class);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
    }
    return this;
}
```

As you can see it uses `ServiceFileTransfomer` which is defined [here](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/transformers/ServiceFileTransformer.groovy). From its docs:

> Modified from org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServiceResourceTransformer.java
>
> Resources transformer that appends entries in META-INF/services resources into a single resource. For example, if there are several META-INF/services/org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder resources
>   spread across many JARs the individual entries will all be
>   concatenated into a single 
>   META-INF/services/org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder resource
>   packaged into the resultant JAR produced by the shading process.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR - It merges the service files in the META-INF/services folder.

**Long Answer**

Some libraries (e.g. Micronaut) create a few service files in the `META-INF/services` folder. These files can contain any information useful at runtime. In case of Micronaut framework, it creates a file that lists the Bean References (or beans that are instantiated) in a file called `io.micronaut.inject.BeanDefinitionReference` under `META-INF/services`.

Usually, if you just have one application, it works fine even without `mergeServiceFiles()`. But if there are two micronaut projects that you are bundling into a single jar (e.g. a micronaut `lib` project with some utils and a micronaut `app` project with core business logic), you will have two `io.micronaut.inject.BeanDefinitionReference`. Each one will contain the beans of it's own project.

If you don't use `mergeServiceFiles()`, one of the `BeanDefinitionReference` files will be overwritten by the other. In that case, you will get a runtime exception saying `BeanNotInstantiated` or something of that sort.

Using `mergeServiceFiles()` merges (or concatenates in this case) the `BeanDefinitionReference` files of both the projects so that at runtime, you get all the beans defined.

More details can be found in the gradle forum topic [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-selective-dependencies-in-fat-jar/39444).